# How do I use num_rows() function in the MySQLDB API for Python?

Tags: python, mysql

I have this statement

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = "SELECT * from table"
cursor.execute(query)
res = cursor.fetchall()
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = "SELECT * from table"
cursor.execute(query)
print cursor.rowcount
```

According to the [Python Database API Specification v2.0](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/), the `rowcount` attribute of the `cursor` object should return the number of rows that the last query produced or affected (the latter is for queries that alter the database). If your database module conforms to the API specification, you should be able to use the `rowcount` attribute.

The `num_rows()` function you are looking for does not exist in the `MySQLdb` module. There is an internal module called `_mysql` which has a `result` class with a `num_rows` method, but you shouldn't be using that - the very existence of `_mysql` is considered an implementation detail.

Answer (score 4):

Most voted answer is not working yet. It should be like that:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = "SELECT * FROM table"
cursor.execute(query)
cursor.fetchall()
print (cursor.rowcount)
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you @oğuzhan-karabulut